# Helm Kafka, can't change the port for Kubernetes pod

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-kafka, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm

I created a kubernetes cluster (GCP GKE) with 2 nodes. I set up zookeeper for druid (port 2181)
I works fine, but, I want to deploy kafka pod in the same cluster. So I use helm, but when I change the port at the end of the script values.yaml, I run helm upgrade like this

helm upgrade kafka -n gke-k8s bitnami/kafka -f values_kafka.yaml

And the pod kafka zookeeper always running in the port 2181 when I use describe pod, even if I delete it or recreate it. At the same time kafka broker pod have the status "CrashLoopBackOff" after update values.yaml

I use this file values.yaml
https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/master/bitnami/kafka/values.yaml

And change it with

```
...
##
zookeeper:
  enabled: true
  port: 2180
  auth:
    ## Enable Zookeeper auth
    ##
    enabled: false
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the value in the ZK chart you need to set is actually [service.port](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/master/bitnami/zookeeper/values.yaml#L227).

So in your Kafka values, it should be

```
...
##
zookeeper:
  enabled: true
  service:
    port: 2180
  auth:
    ## Enable Zookeeper auth
    ##
    enabled: false
...
```